# Difference between simple and complex statement

Tags: javascript

I'm studying w3schools regarding [semicolon placement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp) (under the heading: "Statement Rules") and they said "Always end a simple statement with a semicolon." And: "Do not end a complex statement with a semicolon."  They did not define what the difference between a simple and complex statement is and a thorough online search did not provide an answer either.  So I am still confused with JavaScript semicolon placements.  I would appreciate any help.

Comment: provide a link to the page you're quoting. generally speaking, you just put a semicolon at the end of a statement. there are a few places where they're not required, like after a function definition, but even if you added one after a function, it wouldn't break anything. if you're confused about whether or not a semicolon belongs, try it. also, consider using the MDN website to learn javascript instead of 3wschools. w3s has a tendancy to give innacurate descriptions and examples.

Comment: I don't know if it's proper to post a link to SO's Documentation as an answer or not but there is an article on [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/4363/automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi#t=201608031320000905945)

Comment: As Pamblam said, w3schools is questionable, there are *much* better resources.

Comment: @str thanks, edited.

Comment: They're referring to a simple statement like `throw "ERROR"` vs. a complex statement like `{ a = 1; b = 2; }`. "Complex statement", however, is not correct terminology; the technical term is JS is **block**, or sometimes **compound statement** is used. This is an example of the kind of sloppiness on W3Schools which is why should avoid it. If you had known to Google for "Javascript block", then you would have found plenty of information right away.

Comment: @torazaburo - If this doesn't get incorporated into the existing answers, this should be posted as a separate answer. OP, there are other places with JavaScript tutorials listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 2):

A complex statement is a sequence of ('simple') statements inside `{}`.

So you'd write (simple statement):

```
a = 3;
```

and (complex statement, in many languages called a compound statement, in JavaScript called a BLOCK)

```
{
   a = 3;
   b = 4;
}
```

but not

```
{
   a = 3;
   b = 4;
};
```

Comment: As of ES 6 no longer true, omitting the `;` after defining an arrow function is a syntax error.

Comment: Actually, better called a **block**, which is the standard term. "Compound statement" is used in other programming languages, but is nowhere to be found in the JS spec.

Comment: @JaredSmith Not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the concise body form of an arrow function? That is not a statement, but rather an **expression**.

Comment: @ torazaburo Edited accordingly. In addition, I think a general term like 'compound statement' should be known as well, as it enables one to look over the boundaries of the language one grows up with... But in JS indeed BLOCK is to be preferred.

Comment: @torazaburo if i write a throw-away arrow function (not bound to a name in an assignment expression), using curly braces to delimit the function body, and neglect the semi-colon, then I get a syntax error. Or does that still qualify as an expression? Wrapping the arrow function in parens to force evaluation as an expression does not give the same error: `(() => {})[0]` vs `() => {}[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple statement in JavaScript is a single line of code that performs a specific task and does not require any additional statements to complete its execution. Example: x = 10.

A complex statement, also known as a compound statement, is a group of simple statements that are executed together as a single unit and controlled by a compound statement like if-else, for, while loop, etc. Example:

```
if (x > 10) {
    x = 0;
    y = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex statement refers to blocks like in `if`, `for`, `while` etc.

```
if(condition){

} //no semicolon
```

Simple statement:

```
var x = 2;
```

Comment: A complex statement (which is a wrong and confusing term, not used in JS) doesn't have to be any of things. It can sit there all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, JavaScript allows you to omit the semicolon at the end of a statement. In other cases, it has to be there, or the next line will be treated as part of the same statement. The rules for when it can be safely omitted are somewhat complex and error-prone.

i recommend you check this [Link](https://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html)